# How to get response 'yes' or 'no' using ngx-bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, angular2-template, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx-bootstrap modal, but I want to use something like this

```
confirmDialog(message: string, note: string, onOk, onCancel) {
   // modal open
   // on click onOk button some action perform
   // on click onCancel button some action perform
}
```

So that I can use this method wherever I want to perform both action. Is this possible?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I am using ngx-bootstrap modal for a delete modal. To get it working you will need to use @Input and @Output to pass the refinances to and from the parent. The example below could easily be modified to fill your needs. If you are needing to pass a value from the child to the parent you can do that in the Event Emitter by changing the type to something like `EventEmitter< any >` and on the on the template change it to `(deleteEvent)="delete($event)"` the on the emit pass the value you want to send in the event `this.deleteEvent.emit(true);`.

My Delete Modal ts

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalRef } from "ngx-bootstrap";

@Component({
selector: 'delete-modal',
templateUrl: './delete.modal.component.html'})

export class DeleteModalComponent {
    @Input() modalRef: BsModalRef;
    @Output() deleteEvent = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() { }

    delete(): void {
        this.deleteEvent.emit();
    } 

}
```

My Delete Modal HTML

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title pull-left">Confirm Delete</h3>
</div>     
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>Do you really want to delete item?</p>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" (click)="delete()">Ok</a>
        <a class="btn btn-default" role="button" (click)="modalRef.hide()">Cancel</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

On the Component that I want to display the dialog

```
/*add a template somewhere*/
<ng-template #delete>
    <delete-modal [modalRef]="modalRef" (deleteEvent)="delete()"></delete-modal>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a generic Yes/No component, one way is to create a callback method off initialState, and then use that method to communicate between the Yes/No component and the component that uses it. Similar to what [they are doing](http://effita.com/confirmation-modal-based-on-ngx-bootstrap-modal).